# gThumb Browser and Viewer should have black background, how to do?

Tags: themes, gthumb

I really like gThumb but I hate that gThumb is using my standard ambiance theme when viewing images. The result is that I have a lightgrey background for images but in my opinion images look the best with a black background.

Here is the area I want to have black (look at the red arrow):
[image]

Is there a way that I can configure gThumb or let gThumb use another theme than the rest of my programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paolo Bacchilega from [gThumb Mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gthumb-list/2012-June/msg00001.html) helped me on this:

open

```
dconf-editor
```

browse to org -> gnome -> gthumb -> image-viewer and check the black-background option.