# gThumb 3.2.7 Browser and Viewer how do I set a black background, old fix no longer available on d-conf

Tags: gthumb

I would like to be able to change the background color in gThumb 3.2.7 to black as listed in the answer to this older post, 
[gThumb Browser and Viewer should have black background, how to do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141768/gthumb-browser-and-viewer-should-have-black-background-how-to-do)
is there a way to do this in gThumb 3.2.7?

PS. I checked in d-conf editor and as far as I can tell the old answer does not seem to fit, Then again I could be brain damaged and somehow missed it?

Answer (score 2):

I've mixed the applications and **this answer is not about gThumb**. But I've decided to leave it here at the moment. This answer is about the application **ImageViewer**, that actually is called <sup>[[1]](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Legacy_names)</sup> EoG - Eye of GNOME.

---

You can change the background colour of **ImageViewer** through its settings: `ImageViewer Menu` `>` `Preferences` `>` `Image View [tab]`.

[image]

---

If you want to change the background colour within the application ImageViewer via [**`dconf-editor`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dconf-editor.1.html) go to: `org` `>` `gnome` `>` `eog` `>` `view` `>` `background-color`.

[image]

- Where `rgb(255,255,0)` is the RGB code of the yellow colour <sup>[[2]](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm)</sup>.

---

Or use [**`gsettings`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gsettings.1.html) <sup>[[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971067/how-can-i-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool/971190#971190)</sup>, if you want to change this setting via the command line:

- to `get` the current value use:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.eog.view background-color
  ```
- to `set` a new value use:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.eog.view background-color 'rgb(255,255,0)'
  ```

Comment: Actually this answer isn't about gThumb, I will check about it.

Answer (score 0):

The option `image-viewer` `>` `black-background` is not longer available in **gThumb** since the version 3.2.0: <sup>[[1]](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gthumb-list/2014-October/msg00002.html) [[2]](https://github.com/GNOME/gthumb/blob/master/NEWS)</sup>

```
version 3.2.0
-------------
* always use a dark background in the image viewer
```

```
version 3.1.1
-------------
* Image viewer: use dark background by default, and more neutral color instead of black
```

From `ChangeLog` for version 3.2.0: <sup>[[3]](https://github.com/GNOME/gthumb/blob/3.2.0/ChangeLog.pre-git)</sup>

```
2003-02-03  Paolo Bacchilega  <paolo.bacch@tin.it>
    * src/gthumb.schemas:
    * src/gthumb-window.c (window_new, pref_black_background_changed)
    * src/fullscreen.c (fullscreen_stop, fullscreen_start): added a black_background option to always use a black background for the image viewer.
```

A possible way to change the background is to edit the source code and recompile. <sup>[[4]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package)</sup> But I'm not a so familiar with programming and unfortunately can't help with that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into the code editing bit.  This is a simple thing that I mite be able to get done without making a big mess.

Comment: Hi, @DEH, it would be nice to create an answer when you succeed.

Comment: I just downloaded the code for gThumb, editing it maybe a bigger project than I thought when you mentioned editing the code.  I was thinking something like search one text file of code for "background color" or some such and change some hex color code like 00,00,00 to FF,FF,FF.  But alas I see its not anywhere near that simple.  I first have to figure out which of the 1358 files has the little bit of code in it, then I need to download 15 library files, then I can compile the code.  On further thought I think this mite be something I would need a LOT of help to do.

Comment: PS.  By the way there is a new version of gThumb 3.5.4, it came out 4 days ago.